# If a sentence is quashed, does it mean that there's no sentence at all anymore?

Tags: word-usage, semantics

If a sentence is quashed, does it mean that there's no sentence at all anymore (i.e. the convicted is acquitted) or, if a sentence is only reduced or, say, replaced with probation, the word's applicable as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/quash), quash means

> to say officially that something, especially an earlier official decision, is no longer to be accepted

**quash** is therefore only used if the defendant is acquitted.

If the sentence is reduced in some way, the correct word to use is **[commute](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/commute)**.

Comment: What if there's no actual imprisonment (suspended sentence, a person is released from prison)?

Comment: quashed means completely destroyed. Definitely release from prison, and possibly compensation for wrongful imprisonment.  Changing to a suspended sentence would be **commute**.